# Exception occurred during order load error

Tags: magento2, sales-order

When I am click on order view found: Exception occurred during order load

I am unable to reach order view page.

Comment: Please check for `var\log` folder

Comment: please check var/log/exception.log

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue. I debug and found that there is issue with Magento in the class namely:

**Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Collection**

in the function named **convertAdditionalInfo($info)**

This method does not check for the variable $info is null or array.
So it throws exception.

We can fix this by rewriting this class and overriding function named **convertAdditionalInfo()**

```
private function convertAdditionalInfo($info)
{
    $result = [];
    if (!is_array($info)) {
        return $result;
    }
    foreach ($info as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $result += $this->convertAdditionalInfo($item);
            unset($info[$key]);
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento2.3 .
I got same exception error "Exception occurred during order load".

I found exception in var/log/exception.log file.

I fixed exception error & order view page working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same issue and solve this by below reindex command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the value in the additional_information column in the sales_order_payment table. Please check with the value stored whether you are worked with it in the latest task.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same issue and solve this as below by change deploy mode from developer to production:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Answer (score 0):

First you change the developer mode if it is production mode using below command .

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Check following blog if you face any issue.https://magehit.com/blog/how-to-set-developer-mode-in-magento-2/.

After that you run following command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

you can see errors if it exist in any module.Than you can resolve this issue..

Let me know if you want any more help.